# .htaccess - how to remove last part of url?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove (redirect or substitute) last part of url.

For example, I want

```
www.example.com/cocacola/anything
```

to be

```
www.example.com/cocacola
```

so

```
www.example.com/cocacola/123  or www.example.com/cocacola/cat   ...etc
```

is to be

```
www.example.com/cocacola
```

I was trying hard to figure out this, but still did not find proper solution

This is what I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^(cocacola)\(.+)$ http://example.com/cocacola [R=301,L,NC]
```

How to write .htaccess file to solve the question above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(cocacola)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to maintain the last directory? So on browser, it still shows 'www.example.com/cocacola/something but it functions like www.example.com/cocacola

Comment: oh, so ... it kind of works but not what I want. So if I put www.example.com/cocacola/abc, it redirect to abc.html(?) in cocacola folder. The problem is I don't have cocacola folder. Cocacola is a html file.

Comment: This is my real structure. www.example.com/cocacola.html. but if I put www.example.com/cocacola/abc, it goes to www.example.com/cocacola(folder)/abc.html. What I want is if I put www.example.com/cocacola/abc, then It redirects to www.example.com/cocacola.html with keeping the url I put